# How to mock the callback uri in Postman

Tags: javascript, json, oauth-2.0, postman, bearer-token

I need to test an API automatically in **Postman**, and a part of the testing is OAuth 2.0 flow with the result of bearer token.

I do not have a callback URI (listener) that is able to receive the authorization code once I initiate the OAuth flow.

I need a mock listener in Postman that will be able to receive the authorization code, and send a get token request to the OAuth server, and after that to save the bearer token received in the response.

could someone help me with finding out how to set up a mock listener to receive the code and send get token in Postman?

**My expected result is to be able to save the bearer token received in the environment variable.**